Need to copy data from source to sink, but throwing error as below
I have a source file in ADLS Gen2 and target as sql db. But when im going to copy the data into SQL table, the below error it is giving
Failure happened on 'Sink' side. ErrorCode=SqlOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=A database operation failed. Please search error to get more details.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.InvalidOperationException,Message=The given value of type String from the data source cannot be converted to type nvarchar of the specified target column.,Source=System.Data,''Type=System.InvalidOperationException,Message=String or binary data would be truncated.,Source=System.Data,'
Need answer for that

Have you verified that the source data isn't longer than the target column in the SQL DB table?

I have created a table for sample like below:
create table table2(id int,name nvarchar(5),age int);

This is my source data:
id,name,age
1,Laddu,23
2,M.luffy,19
3,illu,40

When copying, you can see I got same error.

The above error arises when a source column string length is greater than the sink SQL table column's specified length.
While creating, I have given that the column values length as nvarchar(5). In my data the string M.luffy's length is more than this and it is the reason for this error.
So, check your any source column string length and SQL table specified length and make sure the source data is within the given range.
